# Change the level of a factor based on the level of another factor

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, na

I have a data set with many variables, two of which called "animal" and "plant". Both variable are factors, and both are binary, i.e. they are either a text value, or NA.

For example:

```
animal <- c(NA, NA, "cat", "cat", NA)
plant  <- c("ivy", NA, "ivy", NA, NA)
value  <- c(1:5)
df     <- data.frame(animal, plant, value)

> df
  animal plant value
1   <NA>   ivy     1
2   <NA>  <NA>     2
3    cat   ivy     3
4    cat  <NA>     4
5   <NA>  <NA>     5
```

When the value of plant is "ivy" and the value of animal is "cat",
I want to change the value of plant to NA (i,e, the two things can not be true and the animal value takes priority. I don't any changes in my other variables

I've tried the following but get an error message:

```
df <- df %>% if (isTRUE(animal == "cat")) {plant==NA}

Error in if (.) isTRUE(animal == "cat") else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) isTRUE(animal == "cat") else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

My goal output is:

```
> df
  animal plant value
1   <NA>   ivy     1
2   <NA>  <NA>     2
3    cat  <NA>     3
4    cat  <NA>     4
5   <NA>  <NA>     5
```

I would really appreciate any help. I'm sure there is a really simple way of doing this, maybe I can't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be simpler than you think. You can achieve the same result simply by turning all plants, where animal is not `NA`, to `NA`:

```
df$plant[!is.na(df$animal)] <- NA
```

Or a bit fancier:

```
is.na(df$plant) <- !is.na(df$animal)
```

Comment: Thank you! This has absolutely done the trick! I am so so grateful, thank you! I knew there was a simple answer I was missing....

Comment: Happy to hear it helped! In order to close this question properly - feel free to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)    

df %>% 
      mutate(plant = case_when(animal == 'cat' & plant == 'ivy' ~ NA_character_,
                               TRUE ~ plant))
```

This gives us:

```
  animal plant value
1   <NA>   ivy     1
2   <NA>  <NA>     2
3    cat  <NA>     3
4    cat  <NA>     4
5   <NA>  <NA>     5
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really useful - I'm definitely learning a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
df[!(is.na(df$animal)|is.na(df$plant)),'plant'] <- NA
df
  animal plant value
1   <NA>   ivy     1
2   <NA>  <NA>     2
3    cat  <NA>     3
4    cat  <NA>     4
5   <NA>  <NA>     5
```

This can also be expressed as:

```
df[!is.na(df$animal) & !is.na(df$plant),'plant'] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you! This is useful. The example below is very simple and works, but the "&" is new to me and useful. I am so grateful that people share their expertise!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `==` does not work intuitively with the `NA` values in R.

```
> df[df$animal=="cat",]
     animal plant value
NA     <NA>  <NA>    NA
NA.1   <NA>  <NA>    NA
3       cat   ivy     3
4       cat  <NA>     4
NA.2   <NA>  <NA>    NA
```

Here for example all lines are returned because `NA == "ANYTHING"` returns `NA`.

You could define this function which returns `TRUE` if both `x` and `y` are equal and not `NA`,  or if both are `NA`.

```
is.equal.force <- `%===%` <- function(x,y, vect=T) {
  res <- ifelse(is.na(x),is.na(y),ifelse(!is.na(y)&!is.na(x),x==y, NA))
  if(!vect){
    res <- all(res)
  }
  return(res)
}
```

Then the solution to your problem becomes simply:

```
df[df$animal%===%"cat"&df$plant%===%"ivy","plant"] <- NA
df
  animal plant value
1   <NA>   ivy     1
2   <NA>  <NA>     2
3    cat  <NA>     3
4    cat  <NA>     4
5   <NA>  <NA>     5
```

Note that the correct syntax was used here.

Comment: This seems incredibly complex given the task at hand. Is there a benefit to this solution over any of the others provided?

Comment: I am using this function routinely. As soon as you have vectors with *potential* NA values, `==` will produce unexpected results. If you can't see the value in producing error-safe code with respect to `NA` values in the input, I can't help you.

Comment: also note that OP's real data may differ from the somewhat concise toy example he just gave us.

Comment: Thank you - the simple answer above has helped but it's still really helpful to see this answer. I appreciate your time!